# Enable text selection and dragdrop plugin both in viewconfig for Ext JS Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

```js
 viewConfig: {
                                            emptyText: emtyTxt,
                                            stripeRows: false,
                                            enableTextSelection: true,
                                            plugins: {
                                                dragGroup: 'user-dd',
                                                enableDrop: false,
                                                ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop'
                                            }
                                        }
```

how can I enable the text selection and drag and drop both feature using the viewconfig? If I remove the drag drop plugin then the text selection works perfectly but how can I make both of these work together?

Comment: How do you expect them to work together? What should happen when you press mouse down and start dragging?

Comment: But is there any way that I should be able to copy the grid row text and have the drag drop as well?

Comment: If you know an example, show it please. Otherwise I only see that you either: 1) Reserve a draggable area within the row having no text (e.g. the first column); OR 2) Have a switch (e.g. toggle button) that will switch between viewing mode (with text selectable) and drag-drop mode.